# Generation of left ideals in group rings

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, ring-theory, group-rings

This looks like an elementary exercise on group rings (I heard it somewhere), nonetheless it seems to be non-trivial to me. Any references much appreciated.

Suppose that we are given an (infinite) group $G$ and let us consider its group algebra $(\mathbb{C}[G], +, *)$ generated by Dirac deltas $\delta_g\;(g\in G)$. Let $V$ be a linear subspace of $\mathbb{C}[G]$, maximal with respect to the property:

> if $f\in V$ then $f(g\,\cdot\, )\in V$ for each $g\in G$.

Furthermore suppose that there exist elements $g_1, \ldots, g_n\in V$ such that every $f\in V$ can be written as $f=a_1 * g_1 + \ldots + a_n * g_n$ for some $a_1, \ldots, a_n \in \mathbb{C}[G]$.

(Thus $V$ is really a maximal left ideal of $\mathbb{C}[G]$.)

> I would like to known whether there must exist an idempotent $p\in V$ such that $V=\mathbb{C}[G]*p$.

*Notation*: By $f(g\cdot\,)$ I understand the function $h\colon G\to \mathbb{C}$ given by $h(k)=f(gk),\; k\in G$

Comment: Dear Tomek: I think also this question is complex enough people would like to see a reference, if you can find one. If you can't find one, that's fine: it's just a suggestion. Thank you for the clarifying edits, btw.

Comment: I could be misreading something, but the first condition really looks like "maximal left ideal of $\Bbb C[G]$ and the second condition just says that this ideal is finitely generated. I would be a little surprised if all f.g. maximal left ideals of such a ring had to be summands, but I couldn't think of any counterexamples, so I remain puzzled :)

Comment: Yes, this is not very surprising, I think. This is true for C*-algebras for example. Of course, you can complete the group algebra in the C*-norm but f.g. left ideals need not remain f.g. in the completion.

Comment: Furthermore, every closed left ideal in a separable C*-algebra contains a dense principal left ideal.

Comment: OK, so we are drifting into C* and other such functional analysis theory where I will be no help :) Of course I can see this is trivially true if the group algebra happens to be a von Neumann algebra, but of course the group ring isn't von Neumann for arbitrary $G$. I will enjoy seeing the solution to this problem :)

Comment: It is a vNA if and only if $G$ is finite. :-)

Comment: Ah sorry, we are talking about different things. I am not aware of the differences between von Neumann algebras and [von Neumann regular rings](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Von_Neumann_regular_ring). The group algebra over a field of characteristic $0$ is von Neumann regular iff $G$ is locally finite (finite subsets of $G$ generate finite subgroups of $G$.)

Comment: Infinite dimensional Banach algebras are never von Neumann regular as rings. A prototypical example of a von Neumann regular ring is the ring of operators affiliated to a von Neumann algebra, though it cannot be turned to a Banach algebra (hence to a von Neumann algebra either) in general by the above. What you can easily prove, is that if you represent the group algebra on a Hilbert space faithfully and take the WOT closure, then every left ideal (no matter f.g. or not) will be of the form $\mathbb{C}[G]p$ for some idempotent $p$ from the WOT closure.

Comment: That's rather amazing... I hope I someday find time to look at this. I only have [this reference](http://books.google.com/books?id=legpAQAAMAAJ&q=linear+analysis+and+representation+theory&dq=linear+analysis+and+representation+theory&hl=en&sa=X&ei=3gjTUYzjMbKH0QHSs4D4Bg&ved=0CC8Q6AEwAA) but I'm not sure if it's useful. Is it?

Comment: If you mean the same by the group algebra as an algebraist would (the vector space of *finite* linear combinations of group elements, with multiplication defined by extending the group operation bilinearly), then if $G$ is an infinite cyclic group, the augmentation ideal of $\mathbb{C}[G]$ is a maximal left ideal that is finitely generated, but $\mathbb{C}[G]$ has no idempotents except $0$ and $1$.